# jquery closest doesn't want to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

I have repeated down the page an image with a div next to it like this:

```
 <img src="/img/productspage/questionMark.jpg" class="prodQuestionMark" />
            <div class="vuQuestionBubble">
                <p>this is where text for the text will go</p>
            </div>
```

`vuQuestionBubble` has a style display:none by default. when 'prodQuestionMark' is clicked i want the vuQuestionBubble next to it to show. ive put this code at the bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.prodQuestionMark').click(function () {

        $(this).closest('vuQuestionBubble').show();
    });
});
```

it doesn't seem to work... the click event is working and i can select the parent div with .parent but cant seem to interact with the closest div... any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`closest` looks for ancestors, not siblings; also, your selector is missing a `.` at the beginning (you're telling it to look for a `vuQuestionBubble` element, where you really mean a `div` with the class "vuQuestionBubble").

With your current structure, you can use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) because the div with the "vuQuestionBubble" is the very next element. However, if you ever change your structure and put something between them, `next` won't work for you.

I'd probably use `nextAll("div.vuQuestionBubble:first")` or `nextAll(".vuQuestionBubble:first")` (links: [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.prodQuestionMark').click(function () {

        $(this).nextAll('div.vuQuestionBubble:first').show();
        // Or without `div`:
        //$(this).nextAll('.vuQuestionBubble:first').show();
    });
});
```

That will find the first div with the class "vuQuestionBubble" that follows the `img` as a sibling, even if it's not the one *right* next to the `img`, and so makes your code less susceptible to maintenance issues if the markup changes slightly.

Comment: thanks for such an in-depth answer. i didnt know about these functions.

Answer (score 4):

The `closest` function finds the closest ancestor to the element. You actually need to use `.next('.vuQuestionBubble')`.

Comment: You still need the class selector (.)

Answer (score 1):

`vuQuestionBubble` is a class

```
$(this).closest('vuQuestionBubble').show();
=>
$(this).closest('.vuQuestionBubble').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Description: Get the first ancestor
>   element that matches the selector,
>   beginning at the current element and
>   progressing up through the DOM tree

Translated: Closest apparently gets ancestors, not siblings.

ref: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Have a break, have a kit-kat.

Comment: True, but somehow...incomplete. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`closest` traverses to ancestor element, so try `siblings('vuQuestionBubble')`